# Converting plain text list into array in python program

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

The TextFile.txt file contains:

```
1  one    
2  two    
3  three    
4  four    
5  five
```

The python program:

```
file = open ("x.txt", "r")
for item in file:
    x = item.split ('\s')
import numpy as np
a = np.array (x)
print (a)
```

Results:

```
['5 five']
```

But, wanna get all the elements of TextFile.txt as an array. How to achieve the same?

Comment: You want all elements in a single array? Array of arrays? Can you write the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('x.txt') as f:
    print np.loadtxt(f, dtype=str, delimiter='\n')
```

---

```
['1  one' '2  two' '3  three' '4  four' '5  five']
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you loop through each element in the file but you don't save each element, then you convert only the last element to an array.

The following solves your problems:

```
import numpy as np

file = open ("a.txt", "r")
x = []
for item in file:
    x.append(item.split ('\s')) # Process the item here if you wish before appending
a = np.array(x)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), e.g:

```
import numpy as np
np.genfromtxt("TextFile.txt",delimiter='\n',dtype='|S10')
```

Gives:

```
array(['1  one', '2  two', '3  three', '4  four', '5  five'], 
  dtype='|S10')
```